# Recursively delete subdirectories not containing pattern on OSX

Tags: bash, find, patterns

I am trying to delete all sub directories (and files inside) that do *not* contain one of two patterns in the directory name using Bash on OSX. I am trying to do this recursively - for a bunch of parent directories.

Lets say the pattern in sub dirs I want to *not* delete is either "foobar" or "doobar"

I have a whole bunch of Parent directories, like this one:

```
Parent001_dir
   001_boo
   002_hugs
   003_foobar
   004_doobar
   005_apple
   ...
```

I want to run a for loop code that will go into each and every parent dir and delete the non-matching sub dirs.

Code I thought could work:

```
for i in /path/to/parent/directories/
do
find !-name "*foobar*" -o !-name "*doobar*"  -delete
done
```

But I read the find manual and see no option for *not* matching patterns; !-name isn't an option.

EDIT- from comments, trying:

```
find /path/to/parent/directories/ -type d -not -name "*foobar*" -not -name "*doobar*"  -delete
```

and getting a"path potentially not safe" message

If I find a way to fix my code, I could finally get "Parent001_dir" and all other parent dirs to look like:'

```
Parent001_dir
   003_foobar
   004_doobar
```

Are there wildcard characters that could fix my code maybe? Or should I use another approach entirely? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's `! -name` - with a space in between, but the more recommended option is `-prune`, from what I can tell.

Comment: I added the space, but now terminal gives me this (and doesn't delete anything): usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression];
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

Comment: Check the output before rushing off to delete: What does `find ! -name '*foobar*' -o ! -name '*doobar*'` say?

Comment: just doing that part gives the same "usage" output - usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression] ; 
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]

Comment: You don't want the `-o`. In any case, that should have worked. What OS are you running? It looks like your `find` doesn't support `!`. Try with `-not` as in my answer below.

Comment: If it doesn't support `!`, but supports `-delete`, I'd be very surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there;s no need for a loop, `find` can do all of this itself. You can negate conditions using the `!` or `-not` flags. You also don't want `-o` since that would mean "find files/dirs whose name is not foobar or whose name is not doobar". That would find everything since one or the other condition will always be true (`foobar` matches "not doobar" and `doobar` matches "not foobar"). What you wanted is something like:

```
find /path/to/parent/dirs/* -type d ! -name "*foobar*" ! -name "*doobar*" -delete
```

or

```
find /path/to/parent/dirs/* -type -d -not -name "*foobar*" -not -name "*doobar*" -delete
```

You could, if you wish, also do this in the shell. For example, with `bash`:

```
for i in /path/to/parent/dirs/*/; do 
    [[ "$i" =~ 'foobar' || "$i" =~ 'doobar' ]] || rm -rf "$i"; 
done
```

---

I'm not sure about the details and I don't have a mac to test this on, but it looks like the OSX find won't let you delete directories. I believe (but am not sure) that that's what [this code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-116/find/function.c) does:

```c
/* Potentially unsafe - do not accept relative paths whatsoever */
if (strchr(entry->fts_accpath, '/') != NULL)
    errx(1, "-delete: %s: relative path potentially not safe",
        entry->fts_accpath);
```

One way to get around this is to use `-exec` instead:

```
find /path/to/parent/dirs/ -type d ! -name "*foobar*" ! -name "*doobar*"  \
    -exec rm -rf {} +
```

***All of these commands will delete stuff. Test them before use!***

Comment: I think the test for directory can be skipped if you use `**/`.

Comment: @muru true, thanks. In fact, I don't even need `globstar` here since the OP only wants directories.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. I think im close - now I'm getting a "relative path potentially not safe" msg and it's still not deleting

Comment: @JordanGarner what did you run? What's the actual path you are using? What is your OS?

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Using OSX Yosemite, 10.10.5. The actual path is to an external drive: " /Volumes/MRI_data/ENIGMA/840/2R064GH" where 2R064GH is the parent. To test this on just ONE parent dir, I ran "find /Volumes/MRI_data/ENIGMA/840/ -type d -not -name "*MPRAGE*" -not -name "*ep2d*"  -delete" MPRAGE is foobar and ep2d is doobar. Maybe this is a permission issue?

Comment: @JordanGarner first of all, whenever you're testing things like that, run it without the `-delete` first, to make sure you're matching the right things. That said, OSX `find` supports all of `!`, `-not` and `-delete` so I don't see why it wouldn't work. Are any of the directories actually links?

Comment: Good point. I removed "-delete" and it really does match the things I want it to! Thank you for giving me that. So what do you mean by 'actual links'? sorry I am new to this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29829/discussion-between-jordan-garner-and-terdon).